# FirebaseAuth.Instance is null when trying to sign in/create account

Tags: c#, firebase, authentication, xamarin, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to log into Firebase using an Email and Password in Xamarin Forms. Everything was working fine originally until it suddenly stopped. When calling the CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync method, I get a null reference exception because my FirebaseAuth.Instance comes through as null.

I initialise my app and call GetInstance in my MainActivity and the code previously worked so I am unsure of the problem.

MainActivity.cs

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .SetApiKey("--ApiKey--")
        .SetApplicationId("--AppId--")
        .Build();

    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);

    FirebaseAuth authInstance = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

FirebaseAuth.Instance is null

```cs
public async Task<string> RegisterWithEmailPassword(string email, string password, bool isTrainer)
{

    try
    {

        var user = await FirebaseAuth.Instance.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
        var token = await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync(false);

        user.User.SendEmailVerification();

        return token.Token;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;

    }
}
```

I am obviously expecting CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync to use the email and password I provide it to create a new user in my Firebase App. When it tries to add this to my "user" variable I get the exception since Instance is null.

EDIT: After looking a bit deeper, it seems the problem may be coming from the InitializeApp method in MainActivity. Examining my "app" after, the Uid property has this error "Firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: firebase-auth is not linked, please fall back to unauthenticated mode" (see screenshot below). I assume this is why GetInstance() is returning null. After some googling I cannot really find any info on this area that is of use to me.

[Uid error Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWcjh.png)

Comment: Try running the code in debug and release versions. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042407/exception-in-release-but-not-debug

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to downgrade your Firebase NuGets and make sure they have the same version.

---

I had the same problem (`FirebaseAuth.Instance` is `null`, and `Uid` property of `FirebaseApp` is what you described) when I upgraded my Android SDK from v8.1 to v9.0, and along with it these Firebase NuGets from version 60.1142.1 to the latest version:

- Xamarin.Firebase.Auth (71.1605.0)
- Xamarin.Firebase.Common (71.1610.0)
- Xamarin.Firebase.Core (71.1601.0)
- Xamarin.FIrebase.Database (71.1601.0)
- Xamarin.Firebase.lid (71.1710.0)

As you can see the latest versions are not the same (I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem).

---

In addition to these, I also kept getting weird errors like

> The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly.

when I build the solution. After I downgraded them those errors also stopped showing up.

---

Related posts:
[FirebaseAuth.getInstance() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679383/firebaseauth-getinstance-is-null)